# Removing a label from Vertex

Tags: gremlin, amazon-neptune

Amazon Neptune supports multiple labels for a vertex. While I'm able to add a new label to vertex, I couldn't find a way to remove it.

I found out that

```
vertex.addLabel('human')
vertex.removeLabel('human')
```

http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#_multi_label

is not supported on AWS Neptune.

---

Also trying `drop()` labels like properties not working.

Neptune [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/neptune/latest/userguide/access-graph-gremlin-differences.html) says:

```
gremlin> g.addV('label1').property(id, 'customid')
gremlin> g.addV('label2').property(id, 'customid')
gremlin> g.V('customid').label()
==>label1::label2
```

But that way you can only add label nothing about the removal of the label.

I am looking for some way like `removeLabel()` to remove label without removing the vertex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will find this text in the Apache TinkerPop documentation at [1]

***"This is because TinkerPop does not allow the vertex label to be changed after the vertex has been created."***

The ability to change a vertex label after it is created is not allowed per the TinkerPop reference documentation and implementation. This as far as I know is honored by most if not all of the TinkerPop enabled Graph DBs.

The example you found is part of the custom support for Neo4J when connected directly (not via a Gremlin Server style of connection) where the vertex object can be directly manipulated.

If you need the concept of an editable label I would suggest using a property instead. The net result will be about the same in terms of looking up by property versus by label and a lot more portable.

[1] http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#_graphml_reader_writer

Comment: Thank you for your comment I imagined there might be something similar in Neptune because they give some way to add a label. Sadly looks like there is no way to remove labels you added.

Comment: I'm referring [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/neptune/latest/userguide/access-graph-gremlin-differences.html):

    If you try to create a new vertex using the g.addV() and a vertex with that ID already exists, the operation fails. The exception to this is if you specify a new label for the vertex, the operation succeeds but adds the new label and any additional properties specified to the existing vertex. Nothing is overwritten. A new vertex is not created. The vertex ID does not change and remains unique.

Comment: You can add additional labels using Neptune but you cannot remove existing ones. It's an additive operation.  I think the best approach in general is to use a property for something like this rather than the label.